# Non-post quantum primitives in MPC protocols: for and against?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, multiparty-computation

Is it acceptable from a security point of view for an MPC protocol to use non-post quantum cryptographic primitives?

Note that except for secret sharing, which provides information-theoretic security, many primitives are based on computational security.

I am interested in general (system level) and specific (individual primitive level) arguments to answer this question.

Comment: To me the current direction in MPC protocols seems to be "go as fast as possible with acceptable security" and right now "acceptable security" includes non-post-quantum public key cryptography. But note that quite a few MPC protocols rely mostly on symmetric cryptography and / or trust assumptions and the remaining public-key crypto parts can probably be ported to PQ crypto if needed.

Comment: Well, do you know anyone with a working large-scale quantum computer?

Comment: Of course it's ok, but very rarely necessary. 99% of modern MPC protocols are built in a modular way from general primitives (e.g. oblivious transfer), which can later be instantiated under the assumptions you like (post-quantum or not).

Comment: Thanks everyone for putting comments. I understand the current direction. I think this can be closed.

Comment: I think the question is actually interesting [hence edited]. The comments might be converted into answers if people have the inclination.